# error: error: syntax error at or near "Oct" Postgres db

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, typegraphql

I am getting this error "error: error: syntax error at or near "Oct" whenever I want to create a new post in my postgres db using apollo graphql and typeorm. I have checked the code over and over again but can't seem to find the problem. This is my code:

This is the post resolver from post.ts:
`

```
@Mutation(() => Post)
    createPost(@Arg('title') title: string): Promise<Post> {
        //2 sql queries
        return Post.create({ title }).save()
    }
```

`

Comment: It is difficult to spot code errors when you cannot see the code. Post your code. Also extract and post the actual SQL from your obfuscation layers to what is actually sent to Postgres. One possibility: In Postgres double quotes (") indicate an object name, but it looks like you want the value `Oct`. In Postgres values asr single quoted (').

Comment: Sorry about that, this is the sql error that postgres is throwing:                     
    query failed: INSERT INTO "post"("createdAt", "updatedAt", "title") VALUES (Fri Oct 15 2021 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), Fri Oct 15 2021 11:59:34 GMT+0100 (West Africa Standard Time), $1) RETURNING "id", "createdAt", "updatedAt" -- PARAMETERS: ["New post Alert"]
error: error: syntax error at or near "Oct"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue. The error had to do with the data type of the date. The data type I passed initially to the date object using typeorm was just Date so it was reading the type as an Oct and not a string. So I changed the date type to new Date() and it solved the issue.

Instead of:

createdAt: Date

It should be:

createdAt: new Date()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).